# Errors while importing data from flat file to database table

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I got these error message while importing data from flat file to sql server table using import export wizard in ssms :-

[image]

The mapping window :- 
[image]

[image]

I know there is a issue regarding datatype mismatch,how should I overcome that?

Answer (score -1):

As per error, it indicate that your flat file is not in proper format, in file some of the row has messing (, or tab) delimiter.